# VS2019 implement authentication with SQL server

Tags: visual-studio, authentication

I create a new MVC project with user authentication by the following commands.

dotnet new mvc -o ProjectName --auth Individual

However, it's using sqlite database by default. I know that adding -uld will use localDB instead.

I would like to ask if there is any way to use SQL Server directly.

I tried to migrate the sqlite database to SQL server database but there are some error messages during the migration.... Thus, I would like to ask if there is any better way to do it.

Thank you.

Comment: Use the localDB option to generate the project. Update the connection string to refer to a SQL Server instance/database and then run `dotnet ef database update`

Comment: i have 1. created the db "testDB" in SQL server. 2. changed the connection string in appsettings.json to  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=testDB;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }, 3. run the dotnet ef database update

Are they correct?  Thanks

Comment: Assuming no errors were presented during `dontnet ef database update` the testDB should contain the base set of AapNet... tables including a __MigrationHistory table

Comment: I got the following error

Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
Possible reasons for this include:
  * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
  * You intended to execute a .NET Core program, but dotnet-ef does not exist.
  * You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.

Comment: You'll probably need to install the ef-core tools `dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef`. this should enable `dotnet ef` commands. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet

Comment: It works!  Is this command for copying everything (table n data) to the db stated in the connection string?

Comment: The command runs the EntityFramework migrations that are part of the template in to the configured database. The default context will be configured to use the connection string named "DefaultConnection" in Startup.ConfigureServices. It will also update the database for any future migrations that you create.